# NullpointerException in getSupportActionBar

Tags: android

I am trying to set Toolbar title where my code line is

`View customView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
TextView textViewToolbarTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar_title);`

I am getting error as `java.lang.NullPointerException` at

`View customView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();`

Please help.

Comment: Adding a null check on getSupportActionBar() is good thing ?

Comment: are you getting null pointer on `View customView` or `TextView textViewToolBarTitle` ?

Comment: i asked something else. can you post the full logcat in the question ?

Comment: MainActivity extends BaseActivity and in MainActivity, I have
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean inflationStatus = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return inflationStatus;
    }                                                                                                                           and BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity and I have 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        setToolbarTitle();
        return true;
    }

Comment: private void setToolbarTitle() {
        View customView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
        TextView textViewToolbarTitle = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar_title);
     }

Comment: Crash on this line                                                                                      View customView = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

Comment: well, you don't have enough rep to chat. Most prob you are doing error by not extending `ActionBarAppCompatActivity`. Would you be interested in PM using email or discussing here only on comment ?

Comment: Sure. Please share your email id

Comment: @Shubhank, SakshiGupta: This is not how this site works. There is a chat, for extended messaging.

Comment: I know @BobMalooga. i have asked her few times to share logcat but due to no other option left to actually help her i had to help outside the network.

Comment: Well... if she's not collaborative, then don't help her.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access custom view by that way which you have used in your code, for getting custom view use below lines of code in your activity, in onCreate() method after setContentView() line;

```
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_actionbar, null);
```

try this and you will get your view to handle next task and events.